# PHP creating mp3 from different mp3s

Tags: php, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine/Concatenate MP3s on Server Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164562/combine-concatenate-mp3s-on-server-using-php)

I would like to create a 30 minutes mp3 by combining about 1000 small mp3s together.

Is that kind of thing doable using PHP or the ressources usage would be too costly in CPU/bandwidth?

For example, I would like "Ronaldhino dekes player X and is on the run! Great kick! etc."

Comment: PHP is not the tool for this.  You could use PHP to maybe control a commandline tool built for the purpose, but doing it in PHP itself is inadvisable.

Comment: @GordonM So what kind of language is recommended for that purpose? What language/tool/app?

Comment: I know of a library called lame, it seems to be very popular for encoding mp3 files, there is also this question I found while googling 'lame via php' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851200/running-lame-from-php, you might also want to check out the lame website http://lame.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 3):

There is an library called [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/). It has the ability to join multiple MP3 files into one , although I have never used this functionality. There is an demo available at the Source Forge site of getID3 here http://getid3.sourceforge.net/source/demo.joinmp3.phps. It seems that it works around without using any command line system calls.

I have used this library for getting lengths and other data from various media formats. It worked like a charm. However, as said, I have not tested the `CombineMultipleMP3sTo()` function in it...

You should test this as if it would work for you it would be a far easier option than LAME (which is powerful yet rather complicated to use in my opinion).